# How to allow users to edit a post using the sql UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to let users edit the content that they post. The content is seperated into two sections the title and the text. It also has a category but I don't want to let them edit that. So here is the code that is suppose to update any changes to the title:

> $sql = "UPDATE
>
> topics
>
> SET topic_subject = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "
>
> WHERE
>
> topic_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

The code that updates the content has the same format.
I get the id from the url of the page and once they click submit on the editing page the form calls the page that contains this code. It gives me this error:

> An error occurred while inserting your data. Please try again later.
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE topic_id =' at line 4

I am not an expert in SQL and don't know what the problem could be. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing single quotes around your string value:

```
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']);
$topic_id = (is_numeric($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'NULL');
$sql = "
    UPDATE topics
    SET topic_subject = '$subject'
    WHERE topic_id = $topic_id
";
```

My code also assumes `topic_id` is an `int` column, so I'm checking if the value is numeric instead of escaping it.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the error. I tried to modify a post and it doesn't edit the post though.

Comment: Are you executing the SQL query afterwards? The code I posted only builds the query. If you are, please echo `$sql` to see the exact query you are passing to MySQL, and post the results here.

Comment: This is what I got: UPDATE posts SET post_content = 'Testing post.' WHERE post_id = NULL

Comment: @user1363393, that means `$_GET['id']` does not contain a numeric value. Either you are not passing the id, or you're using string ids (in the latter case, surround `$topic_id` in single quotes as I did with `$subject`).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I finally got it working. The page that let the user edit the post had the id but the page that processed the updates didn't so I just added the ?id='.$_GET['id'] .' to the form action and it worked. Awesome. Thanks again.